Stateful Shell Route implementation, back navigation doesn't work
I have an app with a Bottom navigation bar, after navigating between the pages if I click on the back button instead of going back to the previous page the app closes.
The app has in practice 3 actual pages, FeedPage, LibraryPage, and DiscoverPage. HomePage is just there to enclose the scaffold with the bottom navigation bar while MainApp has just some theme stuff.
I am unsure where exactly it's not working I have read multiple tutorial I am not sure where exactly the code is wrong.
Main.dart
void main() => runApp(const MainApp());

final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'root');
final _feedNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'feed');
final _libraryNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'library');
final _discoverNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'discover');

final router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    initialLocation: '/feed',
    routes: [
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
          builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
            return HomePage(navigationShell);
          },
          branches: [
            StatefulShellBranch(navigatorKey: _feedNavigatorKey, routes: [
              GoRoute(
                  path: '/feed',
                  pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                    return const NoTransitionPage(child: FeedPage());
                  })
            ]),
            StatefulShellBranch(navigatorKey: _libraryNavigatorKey, routes: [
              GoRoute(
                  path: '/library',
                  pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                    return const NoTransitionPage(child: LibraryPage());
                  })
            ]),
            StatefulShellBranch(navigatorKey: _discoverNavigatorKey, routes: [
              GoRoute(
                  path: '/discover',
                  pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                    return const NoTransitionPage(child: DiscoverPage());
                  })
            ])
          ])
    ]);

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
        title: 'Comics',
        routerConfig: router,
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        darkTheme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
        themeMode: ThemeMode.system);
  }
}

home_page.dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage(this.child, {super.key});

  final StatefulNavigationShell child;

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Row(children: [
        Icon(Icons.movie),
        SizedBox(
          width: 8,
        ),
        Text('Comics')
      ])),
      body: widget.child,
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
          onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
            widget.child.goBranch(index);
          },
          selectedIndex: widget.child.currentIndex,
          destinations: const [
            NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.fiber_new), label: 'Feed'),
            NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.book), label: 'Library'),
            NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: 'Discover'),
          ]),
    );
  }
}


Just a thought, does the App close or does it die? ( Check for error messages)

I have been trying it on my phone, I made an error when explaining.
The app doesn't close it just minimise itself probably because there is nothing on to pop on the navigation stack. I can bring it back up by swiping around.
That said I guess goBranch() like context.go() doesn't push anything to the navigation stack, on the other hand context.push() does and still works even though I am using go router. I read that there classes while different can work together but I figured there was a 'proper way', I guess the proper way is to use context.push() even with go router.

Unfortunately this brings me another issue, that is, when I press the back button StatefulNavigationShell does work correctly and goes to the previous page but the BottomNavigationBar.selectedIndex doesn't get updated, so now I am trying to figure that out.
